# Cobertura instrument war

Tags: java, maven, ant, cobertura

I am attempting to instrument wars with Cobertura 1.9.4.1. For this, I use the following ant task, which is invoked using the maven-antrun-plugin:

```
<target name="instrumentEar">
    <cobertura-instrument todir="${module}/target/${ear.dir}">
        <includeclasses regex="nl.*" />
        <fileset dir="${module}/target/${ear.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.war"/>
        </fileset>
    </cobertura-instrument>
</target>
```

Upon execution the output is:

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (instrument) @ my-ear ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

instrumentEar:

[cobertura-instrument] Cobertura 1.9.4.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
[cobertura-instrument] Instrumenting 2 files to D:\workspace\my-ear\target\my-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[cobertura-instrument] Cobertura: Error closing output stream.
[cobertura-instrument] java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP file must have at least one entry
[cobertura-instrument]  at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.finish(ZipOutputStream.java:304)
[cobertura-instrument]  at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:146)
[cobertura-instrument]  at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.close(ZipOutputStream.java:321)
[cobertura-instrument]  at net.sourceforge.cobertura.util.IOUtil.closeOutputStream(IOUtil.java:165)
[cobertura-instrument]  at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentationToArchive(Main.java:319)
[cobertura-instrument]  at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.parseArguments(Main.java:488)
[cobertura-instrument]  at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.main(Main.java:514)
[cobertura-instrument] Cobertura: Error closing output stream.
[cobertura-instrument] java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP file must have at least one entry
[cobertura-instrument]  at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.finish(ZipOutputStream.java:304)
[cobertura-instrument]  at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:146)
[cobertura-instrument]  at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.close(ZipOutputStream.java:321)
[cobertura-instrument]  at net.sourceforge.cobertura.util.IOUtil.closeOutputStream(IOUtil.java:165)
[cobertura-instrument]  at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentationToArchive(Main.java:319)
[cobertura-instrument]  at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.parseArguments(Main.java:488)
[cobertura-instrument]  at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.main(Main.java:514)
[cobertura-instrument] Cobertura: Saved information on 0 classes.
[cobertura-instrument] Instrument time: 67ms
```

It seems ant is unable to read the wars that have been created by maven. I can remember from a long time ago I had problems with the java zip implementation and used the one from ant. Could it be something similar is happening here, but reversed?

[This thread](http://cobertura.996293.n3.nabble.com/Instrumenting-war-file-using-command-line-td3253.html) suggests this should work, but some people recommend extracting the wars first before instrumenting.

Has anybody had any success with the ant task (cobertura-instrument) to instrument wars in place?

Comment: why not use the maven cobertura plugin? http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/

Comment: Because I want to aggregate coverage from multiple modules, including selenium tests, as described [here](http://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/test-coverage-in-a-multi-module-maven-project/).

Comment: I would try to use different source and destination directories. You are using ${module}/target/${ear.dir} for both here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by instrumenting the class files from the different projects included in the WAR seperately and then merging them to the directory from where the application server is started.

I already instrumented the individual projects to get coverage per project, so the merge action was all that was actually needed to be be added.

So no need to instrument the WAR.